# Google Container Engine - How do I configure the amount of logs to keep?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I am using [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) (GKE), how do I configure the amount of logs [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) will retain (preferably: the number of days)?

Answer (score 3):

Stack driver logging agent sends the logs to the cloud logging. By default it keeps 30 days of log. You can extend it by exporting  the logs to Google storage.

**update**

it is possible to export your logs to a Cloud Storage bucket, to a BigQuery dataset, or to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub. In those cases, logs entries are stored immediately and exported according to your configuration as follows:

- Log entries are saved to Cloud Storage buckets in hourly batches, and it might take up to two hours before the entries begin to appear.
- Log entries are streamed to BigQuery datasets and should appear right away, according to the BigQuery streaming data availability guidelines.
- Log entries are streamed to Cloud Pub/Sub topics and should appear right away if there is a subscriber prepared to read them in a timely fashion

details on how to do it it can be read on
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs

Nearline cloud storage should cost you peanuts :)

Comment: So there is no direct way of configuring the number of days to keep? How do you export the logs to Google Storage, concretely?

Comment: i added a separate answer bellow, since it didn't fit in the comment box.

Comment: You should add the instructions to your answer instead of linking to Google documentation, as linking to external resources in SO answers is considered bad etiquette (as links go bad).